# DLL problem after compile with cx_freeze when I use win32wnet importation

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, pywin32

I create a script that connect to network folder with specific username and password that I don't give to user. This script connecto to network folder for 1 or 2 secondes, do stuff and disconnect after that to be sure user can't access network folder after that.

I work fine in my developpement environment. 
I user cx_Freeze to convert my .py to .exe ( I use it for other little program many times )

Problem is that the .exe file works fine only on the same PC where I develop my app. On all other PC it give me error : File " network.py" line 1, in  ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable ( in english, it can't find the specified module )

I try to add DLL of win32wnet. but not working.

What I do wrong.

See my code and my import code

'''

```
import win32wnet
import os
import re

# configure initial parameter
shareFolder = "\\\\ultra\\circuit-bgo"
usager = "foo"
motPasse = "foo"


# use win32wnet to create resorce to connect or disconnect
net_resource = win32wnet.NETRESOURCE()
net_resource.lpRemoteName = shareFolder


# try to disconnect to be sure no connection steel exist
try:
    win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2(net_resource.lpRemoteName,0,0)
except:
    pass

# create connection to network folder
laConnection = win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(net_resource, motPasse, usager, 0)


if os.path.exists(net_resource.lpRemoteName):
    print("connection réussi")
    # do some stuff, like read write and modify some files ( 1 or 2 secondes )
else:
    print("connection ÉCHOUÉ")
    # opps, connection failed

# disconnect to the network folder. I don't want user can access the folder by itself
try:
    win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2(net_resource.lpRemoteName,0,0)
except:
    pass
```

'''

Import code with cx_freeze

'''

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

#syspath = "c:\\Python32\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\perfmondata.dll"

buildOptions = dict(
    packages=['win32wnet'],
    excludes=[],
    include_files=['perfmondata.dll',]
)

executables = [Executable('network.py', base=base)]

setup(name='TestNetwork',
      version='0.1',
      options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
      description='NetWork',
      executables=executables
      )
```

'''

and I try the basic code when I normaly compile with cx_freeze

this is a batch file:

cxfreeze.bat "c:/Python32/Scripts/network.py" --base-name=Win32GUI --target-dir C:/Python32/Scripts/Dist_Network --icon c:/Python32/Scripts/Logo.ico

Comment: Please try to write more clearly.

Comment: sorry, my english is not good

Answer (score 1):

After many, many, many test and reinstallation of python and module I need to find DLL that give me problem. I found that 3 DLL files have to be copy to the same folder of my new .exe file ( program ). The 3 DLL files are : pythoncom32.dll, pythoncomloader32.dll and pywintypes32.dll You can find this files on c:\Windows\syswow64 or system32 depend of your python installation (32 bit or 64 bit)

If you have bether solution, you can add it.

Thanks